# issue with if/else conditions with radio elements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm not good with Javascript and I'm trying to build a two-question quiz based on yes-no answers. When I look at the console I see the yes-no values if I do console.log(answer1 + answer3); But the alert doesn't work. If I remove .checked and do equal to true/false the first alert works.

Any help would be appreciated

```
var answer1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
var answer2 = document.getElementById('q2').value;
var answer3 = document.getElementById('q3').value;
var answer4 = document.getElementById('q4').value;


if (answer1.checked && answer3.checked) {
alert('walking park');

}
else if (answer1.checked && answer4.checked) {
alert('no walk in park');
}
else if (answer2.checked && answer4.checked ) {
alert('oh noooo!');
}
else if (answer2.checked && answer3.checked) {
alert('cor blimey gov!');
}


<form>
   <p>Question 1</p>
   <fieldset>
   <label for="Question1">Can your dog eat food?</label>
   <input type="radio" id="q1" name="question1" value="yes"> Yes<br>
   <input type="radio" id="q2" name="question1" value="no"> No
   </fieldset>

   <p>Question 2</p>
   <fieldset>
   <label for="Question2">Can your dog run in the park</label>
   <input type="radio" id="q3" name="question2" value="yes"> Yes<br>
   <input type="radio" id="q4" name="question2" value="no"> No
   </fieldset>
   <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-med btn-brand-one">submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: maybe the browser has disabled those alerts. Try with some other browser or incognito window. If `console.log` is working, so should `alert`

Comment: `answer1` is either `'yes'` or `'no'` because that's the value of the radio button. You're effectively doing `'yes'.checked` which is nonsensical.

Comment: So how do I get it to run the alert if each radio button is checked, based on question 1 and question 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `checked == true` or simply `checked` and remove `.value`

```js
answer1 = document.getElementById('q1');
 answer2 = document.getElementById('q2');
 answer3 = document.getElementById('q3');
 answer4 = document.getElementById('q4');

function checkanswear(event){
event.preventDefault()
if (answer1.checked && answer3.checked) {
alert('walking park');

}
else if (answer1.checked&& answer4.checked) {
alert('no walk in park');
}
else if (answer2.checked && answer4.checked ) {
alert('oh noooo!');
}
else if (answer2.checked && answer3.checked) {
alert('cor blimey gov!');
}
}
```

```html
<form>
   <p>Question 1</p>
   <fieldset>
   <label for="Question1">Can your dog eat food?</label>
   <input type="radio" id="q1" name="question1" value="yes"> Yes<br>
   <input type="radio" id="q2" name="question1" value="no"> No
   </fieldset>

   <p>Question 2</p>
   <fieldset>
   <label for="Question2">Can your dog run in the park</label>
   <input type="radio" id="q3" name="question2" value="yes"> Yes<br>
   <input type="radio" id="q4" name="question2" value="no"> No
   </fieldset>
   <button onclick="checkanswear(event)" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-med btn-brand-one">submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Why would you ever write `== true`?

Comment: `answer1.checked == true` or `answer1.checked` is the same dosen't mather

Comment: So why did you say that was the solution, as if it made a difference?

Comment: When I remove the value and run console.log(answer1 + answer3); I get  back [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: @Tyrone you want to console.log the value of the checked answear ?

Comment: @Tyrone Indeed. If you want to output the string value, you need `console.log(answer1.value + answer3.value)`.

Comment: thanks. it's working I noticed the problem was with the spelling on the button onclick. thanks again.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it still recommends `== true`.

Comment: ... and it still says "Use `checked == true`".

Comment: @melpomene Use `checked == true`  **or** simply `checked`  maybe the OP or someone else  will benefit from this information facing similar issue  knowing that both statement are the same

Comment: No, that's like saying "use `!!checked` or `(checked == false) == false` or `!checked != !false` or ...". It's simply obfuscation. It's completely irrelevant to the problem at hand, and OP already has plain `checked` in his code.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the `.value` of your checkboxes is the string `"yes"` or `"no"`. Strings don't have a `checked` attribute.

Solution: Just remove the `.value` part. Let `answer1`, `answer2`, etc be the input elements themselves. Then you can use `.checked` on them.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById('myBtn').onclick = function() {
    var answer1 = document.getElementById('q1');
    var answer2 = document.getElementById('q2');
    var answer3 = document.getElementById('q3');
    var answer4 = document.getElementById('q4');


    if (answer1.checked && answer3.checked) {
      alert('walking park');

    } else if (answer1.checked && answer4.checked) {
      alert('no walk in park');
    } else if (answer2.checked && answer4.checked) {
      alert('oh noooo!');
    } else if (answer2.checked && answer3.checked) {
      alert('cor blimey gov!');
    }
};
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Question 1</p>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="Question1">Can your dog eat food?</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q1" name="question1" value="yes"> Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="q2" name="question1" value="no"> No
  </fieldset>

  <p>Question 2</p>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="Question2">Can your dog run in the park</label>
    <input type="radio" id="q3" name="question2" value="yes"> Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" id="q4" name="question2" value="no"> No
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-med btn-brand-one">submit</button>
</form>
```